# Magento 1.9 cron jobs runs every 5mint but its configured for every 1 minute

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cron, crontab, magento-cron

Through cpanel I have configured `cron.sh` to run every 5 minutes **(working)**.

I have added a custom module meant to run every 1 minute **(code below)**.

The issue is that the cron is not running every **1 minutes as configured in module**, but it is running every 5 mintutes as configured through cpanel. How I can configure to run per minute in this module?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Tweaks>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Tweaks>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customtest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Atwix_Tweaks</module>
                    <frontName>runcron</frontName>
                </args>
            </customtest>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <tweaks>
                <class>Atwix_Tweaks_Block</class>
            </tweaks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Atwix_Tweaks_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
        <models>
             <Atwix_Tweaks>
                <class>Atwix_Tweaks_Model</class>
            </Atwix_Tweaks>
        </models>
    </global>

 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <Atwix_Tweaks>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>Atwix_Tweaks/observer::test</model></run>
            </Atwix_Tweaks>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you share your crontab configuration?

Comment: Please check screenshoot -> [link](http://techcruz.com/cron.JPG)

Comment: Please change on cpanel 5 minutes to 1 minutes.